# Is it possible to some class method before executing other class methods?

Tags: javascript

For example I have JS(ES6) class

```
class ClassA {

    constructor() {        
        /*  some constructor body */      
    }    

    initMetond() {                
        /*  some method body */  
    }

    method1() {
        /*  some method1 body */
    }

    method2() {
        /*  some method2 body */
    }

    method3() {
        /*  some method3 body */
    }
}
```

And I need to have initMethod() to be executed before any other class method (but not in the constructor). At the moment I did it as following

```
class ClassA {

    constructor() {        
        /*  some constructor body */      
    }    

    initMetond() {                
        /*  some method body */  
    }

    method1() {
        this.initMetond();
        /*  some method1 body */
    }

    method2() {
        this.initMetond();
        /*  some method2 body */
    }

    method3() {
        this.initMetond();
        /*  some method3 body */
    }
}
```

But, I hope, it could have more nice implementation. 
Please advice?

Comment: “Nicest” probably depends on your aesthetical preferences. Your current solution is nice.